# Two independent TOCs

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I wonder if there is any way to achive two independent TOCs. For example I write a document and have my regular `\tableofcontents` right after my titlepage. For some reason I have a long appendix and one part of this appendix is really long with several subsections and subsubsections.

Is there a way to create my regular `\tableofcontents` (without the many subsections and subsubsections of the one appendix section) plus a special TOC just for those subsecions and subsubsections I skipped in my regular TOC?

The first part would be easy with `\subsection*{...}` but how to let them appear  in the second TOC?

I'm aware of the [`minitoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) package, but this needs all subsections to appear in my regular TOC.

I'm using MikTeX with pdfLaTeX and the `scrartcl` class if that is an important information. I'm a LaTeX user for many years but here my knowledge comes to an end. I searched for some time but wasn't able to find anything regarding this issue.

I hope my question is understandable, if not I'm happy to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use the [titletoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package; another option could be the [minitoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) package. Here's an example using `titletoc`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\startcontents
\printcontents{ }{1}{}

\section{A Regular Section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one one}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one two}

\appendix

\section{A Long Appendix}
\stopcontents

\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{ }{2}{}

\subsection{First subsection in Appendix}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one one in Appendix}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one two in Appendix}

\subsection{Second subsection in Appendix}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection two one in Appendix}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection two two in Appendix}
\stopcontents[sections]

\resumecontents
\section{A short appendix}
\subsection{First subsection in short appendix}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection in short appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the optional argument for `\startcontents`, `\printcontents`, and `\stopcontents` you can control the inner table of contents, allowing you to resume the global ToC.

The third mandatory argument of `\printcontents` can be used to produce headings for the ToCs, so, for example, for he general ToC one could use

```
\startcontents
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}% if a change of the default "Contents" name is required
\printcontents{ }{1}{\section*{\contentsname}}
```

and for the partial ToC (although perhaps this partial ToC doesn't require an explicit heading) you could say something like

```
\startcontents[sections]
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of my Long Appendix}
\printcontents[sections]{ }{2}{\subsection*{\hspace*{1.2em}\contentsname}}
```

Comment: Wow... never expected such a quick answer. I just tried it, it just looks like what I was thinking of! Marvelous!

Comment: I integrated this solution in my document but another question appeared. How to integrate further appendix sections (after the long appendix) in the first TOC? My very long appendix is not the last section. I found \resumecontents but it seems not to work with nested \startcontents ... \stopcontents

Comment: @S.H.: please see my updated answer.

Comment: While working with it now on a daily basis just one little question appeared. How to add for each TOC a different name. The first TOC would be "Table of Contents" as the second TOC should be "Table of My Long Appendix". Using `\printcontents[Table of Contents]{}{1}{}` created some errors and I tried to name the different TOCs accordingly with `\startcontents[Table of Contents]`, but this resulted in this error: `Missing number, treated as zero.`

Comment: @S.H.: see my updated answer.

Comment: The same developer of minitoc has also written the package [shorttoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/shorttoc). The development of both packages minitoc and shorttoc is inactive. Which of the packages would you recommend to work with multi-file document where I compile separate parts with [Subfiles](ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf) pkg and trying to get independent TOCs in each separate compilation with different depth? Shorttoc or is there any TOC pkg actively developed and recommended to use?

Comment: I moved my question about individual TOCs and Subfiles to this thread [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284773/which-toc-pkg-to-work-with-subfiles-pkg-for-unique-toc-compilation-with-each-sub).

Comment: But te TOCs have the same style. Is possible to have two different TOC with two different style?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina please were can i found the DOC for \printcontents

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) package.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A Regular Section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one one}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one two}

\appendix

\etocsettocdepth.toc{section}% will be obeyed by main TOC

\section{A Long Appendix (with its own TOC)}

\etocignoretoctocdepth % of course, if we want to see something in local TOC...
\etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{\contentsname}}{}
\localtableofcontents

\subsection{First subsection in Appendix}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one one in Appendix}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one two in Appendix}

\subsection{Second subsection in Appendix}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection two one in Appendix}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection two two in Appendix}

\etocsettocdepth.toc{subsubsection}% will be obeyed by main TOC
\section{A short appendix}
\subsection{First subsection in short appendix}
\subsubsection{First subsubsection in short appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Observe that the indents of the local TOC (as in the other answer) are as if the material was printed as part of the main TOC. To modify this, various ways, one of the most accessible being via using `tocloft` which allows easily modify such indents.