# How do I set up two independent tables of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I am editing a novel in `memoir` class that requires a table of contents for the whole book (introduction, preface, chronology, bibliography, etcetera) and another independent table of contents for just the original novel (author's preface, chapters).  I have been trying to use the `shorttoc` for the book material and the regular toc for the original novel material, but I cannot get the introduction and whatnot to appear in the `shorttoc` alone.

This is the structure that I want:

```
\shorttoc
Introduction 
Note on the Text
Chronology
Novel
   \toc
   Author's Preface
   Book One
   Chapter One
   Etcetera
Bibliography
```

I am not married to the `shorttoc` approach, so any solution would be welcome, especially if there is a way to create two completely independent tables of contents where I could just `\addcontenstline` to one or the other or both.

Update: Using Caramdir's solution, I can get the two tables of contents to appear, but I cannot get them to populate.  Here is my code.  The individual `\addcontents` lines are in the included files, but I have also tried them in the main file with the same results:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\title{The Napoleon of Notting Hill}
\author{G. K. Chesterton}
\date{2012}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ccicons}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\pagestyle{empty}

\include{maintitle}

\newpage

\include{license}

\newpage

\include{dedication}

\newpage

\pagestyle{simple}

\startcontents
\printcontents{}{-1}{\chapter*{Table of Contents}}

\newpage

\include{introduction}

\newpage

\include{chronology}

\newpage

\mainmatter

\include{title}

\endcontents

\newpage

\startcontents
\printcontents{}{-1}{\chapter*{Contents}}

\include{chapterx} %etcerera

\endcontents

\endmatter

\nobibintoc
\include{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Caramdir - The solution at [Two independent TOCs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48900/two-independent-tocs) would work as well, but neither solution will populate for me.  I even cut the code straight from each into a test file, compiled twice, and still got empty headers.  I am using ScribTeX to compile online.  Might this have something to do with it?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48900/two-independent-tocs solve your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the self-reference of the ToC from the ToC?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10943/how-to-remove-the-self-reference-of-the-toc-from-the-toc)

Comment: I don't know: personally, I have neither used `titletoc` nor ScribTeX.

Comment: The issue was in ScribTex and has now been addressed by the admin.  Gonzalo Medina's solutions here and in <a href="http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48900/two-independent-tocs"> http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48900/two-independent-tocs</a> now both work well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [titletoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package allows you to obtain partial (independent) ToCs. The following example illustrates the procedure and also shows how to manually include (*via* `\addcontentsline`) entries in each one of the ToCs:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\startcontents
\printcontents{}{-1}{\chapter*{Short ToC}}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{ptc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chapter*{Note on the Text}
\addcontentsline{ptc}{chapter}{Note on the Text}
\chapter*{Chronology}
\addcontentsline{ptc}{chapter}{Chronology}
\chapter*{Novel}
\addcontentsline{ptc}{chapter}{Novel}

\stopcontents

\startcontents
\printcontents{}{-1}{\chapter*{Contents}}

\chapter*{Author's Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Author's Preface}
\part{Book One}
\chapter{Chapter One }
\chapter{Chapter Two}

\stopcontents

\end{document}
```

An image of the obtained ToCs

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for the example, @GonzaloMedina; I wander why the manual doesn't have something like this `:)` Note to self: the manual's wording "_\startcontents[<name>] - ... a partial toc begins ... The <name> argument allows different sets of tocs..._" made me think that partial tocs are saved to files `\jobname.<name>` ; however, there is only **one** file for partial tocs, `\jobname.ptc` - and inside, different partial tocs are differentiated via `\ttl@starttoc {<name>@1}` (and corresponding ..stoptoc...) Many thanks again - cheers!