# How to remove a part in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc

I want to have two table of contents in one document so I used the package `etoc` and I had two table of contents of the same contents, I want like this

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents % the first
\chapter{chapitre 1}% I want just this chapter in the first table of contents
\section{hello}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapitre2} % I want just this chapter in the second table of contents
\section{HELLO}
\end{document}
```

Any help please

Comment: Most people use minitoc instead  for this.

Comment: Thank you, I used the package titletoc and the result was beautiful thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method using the `etoc` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}

\etocsettocstyle{\chapter*{First TOC (just chapter 1)}}{}
\tableofcontents \ref{toc:chapter 1}% the first

\chapter{chapitre 1}% I want just this chapter in the first table of contents
\invisiblelocaltableofcontents \label{toc:chapter 1}
\section{hello}

\etocsettocstyle{\chapter*{Second TOC (just chapter 2)}}{}
\tableofcontents \ref{toc:chapter 2}% the first

\chapter{chapitre2} % I want just this chapter in the second table of contents
\invisiblelocaltableofcontents \label{toc:chapter 2}
\section{HELLO}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\begin{document}
\startcontents
\printcontents{}{-1}{\chapter*{Table des matière}}
\chapter{Chapitre 1}
\section{hello}
\stopcontents
\startcontents
    \printcontents{}{-1}{\chapter*{Table des matière}}
    \chapter{Chapitre 2}
    \section{Hello}
    \stopcontents
\end{document}
```

thanks to [How do I set up two independent tables of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50280/how-do-i-set-up-two-independent-tables-of-contents)