# Split tableofcontent into two

Tags: table-of-contents, report

I'm rather inexperienced to `LaTeX` and I have run into an issue regarding ToC. 
I have a `report` with an appendix. 
I wish to have a standard `ToC` over the report, and only show the chapter "Appendix" in this `ToC`. 
In my Appendix I would like another `ToC` containing the appendix and only the appendix.

Something like this:

```
ToC1
Capter1............1
  section1.........1
  section2.........3
Chapter2...........5
  section1.........5
ChapterAppendix...10

ToC2
ChapterAppendix ..10
 Section1.........10
  Subsection1.....11
```

I have tried following this example: [Two independent TOCs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48900/two-independent-tocs)
but without luck. 
Can someone give me a clue on what to do?

Comment: See a possible solution here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345979/printing-a-separate-list-of-appendices