# Printing a separate list of appendices

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I am trying to print a List of Appendices (LoA) for my thesis, separate from the Table of Contents (ToC).

I wish for my ToC to look like this, with depth up to subsections (2?):

```
CONTENTS

CHAPTER
  I. Introduction......1
   1.1 Section title...1
    1.1.1 Subsection...1

Appendices ..... 2
```

and for an LoA on a new page, with depth 0, thus:

```
APPENDICES

APPENDIX
A. Proof of Theorem 1...1
B. Proof of Theorem 2...1
```

I am trying to achieve this using the `report` class, in a way that allows me to type appendices using the hierarchy that I obtain from the `chapter`, `section` commands. This is as opposed to defining a custom `myappendix` command into which I insert my appendix content. (I realize that I only need the titles from the appendix chapters for the LoA, but I'd like for the appendix content to have such structure.)

For instance, this approach would solve my problem:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section title}
\subsection{Subsection}
% \begin{appendices} is also acceptable
\appendix  
% Some settings are changed now
\chapter{Proof of Theorem 1}
\chapter{Proof of Theorem 2}
% \end{appendices} if environment is begun
```

whereas the following approach would **not**:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section title}
\subsection{Subsection}
\myappendix{Proof of Theorem 1}
\myappendix{Proof of Theorem 2}
```

I realize several questions have been asked regarding this before, but none of them quite solved my problem. Notably, [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26732/how-to-get-a-list-of-appendices) defines a custom appendix command; [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39896/separate-table-of-appendices-pdf-bookmarks-avoid-previous-chapters-format) defines two custom commands to maintain some hierarchy, but I will have to do more work to handle the inclusion of another layer (subsection) into the appendix.

[This reply](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113836/121631) is the closest to what I want: it does give me a separate LoA, but it also adds appendices to ToC and I can't quite figure out how to suppress the entires in ToC. The moment I use

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
```

the line

```
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toa}}{}{}%
```

fails because I am not adding anything to the ToC anymore.

**My approach:** Since I was using `titlesec` and `tocloft` packages anyway, I tried to do the following:

1. Stop ToC once `appendix` command is issued
2. Start a new counter for appendices using `tocloft`
3. Using the *`<after-code>`* option of `titlesec`, add contents line after every `chapter`.

My **MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for arbitrary text

\usepackage{tocloft,etoolbox,titlesec}
\newcommand{\listappendixname}{List of Appendices}
\newlistof{appendix}{apc}{\listappendixname}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\appendix}{
    \clearpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}}
    \titleformat 
    {\chapter} 
    [display]
    {\huge\bfseries\filcenter} 
    {\Large \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp} \thechapter} 
    {1.5ex}{}
    {\refstepcounter{appendix} \addcontentsline{apc}{appendix}{\protect{\@chapapp \thechapter}}}
}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listofappendix

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[3]

\appendix

\chapter{Proof of Theorem One}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter{Proof of Theorem Two}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

produces the following LoA:

```
List of Appendices

Appendix...... 5
```

It doesn't get the Appendix title or number, and fails after the first one.

Could you please help me obtain a separate LoA in a way that I can still use LaTeX's `chapter`, `section`, ... hierarchy? (I am okay with using different packages, the `book` class, or any approach other than mine.)

Comment: Untested yet, but `titlesec` and `tocloft` in combination is not well!

Comment: I was willing to forego either (or both) in favor of a "nice" solution. In any case your solution below, which I accepted, addresses the heart of my problem: stop writing to the .toc aux file, and write to a different aux file while in appendices :)

Comment: In fact, you still write to the `.aux` file, but this will use the other `toc` related file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fiddling with `\addcontentsline` can be tricky, due its asynchronous writing via `\@writefile`, taking place in the `.aux` file.

I used another approach, letting all structuring commands do what they should, writing to `toc`, however, the `toc` file handle is copied to be `apc` in the `.aux` file and reestablishing it later after the end of the `appendices` environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for arbitrary text

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{tocloft,titlesec}
\newcommand{\listappendixname}{List of Appendices}
\newlistof{appendix}{apc}{\listappendixname}


\makeatletter


\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
  \clearpage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
  \write\@auxout{%
    \string\let\string\latex@tf@toc\string\tf@toc% Store the original `\tf@toc` file handle
    \string\let\string\tf@toc\string\tf@apc% 
  }% Naughty trick
  \titleformat 
  {\chapter} 
  [display]
  {\huge\bfseries\filcenter} 
  {\Large \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp} \thechapter} 
  {1.5ex}{}
  {}
}

\AtEndEnvironment{appendices}{%
  \write\@auxout{%
    \string\let\string\tf@toc\string\latex@tf@toc% 
  }% Naughty trick, restoring the old `\tf@toc` number, to be able to write stuff to the real `.toc` again.
}

\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listofappendix

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{Proof of Theorem One}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter{Proof of Theorem Two}
\lipsum[5]
\end{appendices}

\chapter{Foo stuff}

\end{document}
```

[image]