# How can I create two different lists of figures under two different names?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I am writing a dissertation. The images I have are varying between charts and regular images. I want them to be listed under :

`Table des figures` and `Tables des graphiques`.

I can only make one using `figure`, how can I generate the second?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you want them to have different counters?

Comment: Have you looked into the `float` package and its `\newfloat` mechanism for creating new floats?

Comment: Something like here?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350394/how-to-have-separate-list-of-appendix-figures

Comment: Thanks. Counters? if you mean titles and numbers, then yes.

Comment: No I haven't tried float , is it simple? Thank you

Comment: @Mico: Sorry, I did not see your comment about `float` etc. I can remove my answer if you want to provide a solution of your own.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- No! Do keep your answer. It's just fine. In fact, I just upvoted it. :-)

Comment: @Mico: Ok, thanks, but that was not the purpose of my comment... :D

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I know. [Get the Star Wars reference? :-) ]

Comment: @Mico... er.... no....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Hint: What does Han Solo say to Princess Leia after she says that she loves him? (Ok, I can already here you groan...)

Comment: @Mico: Oh my... and it was that obvious ... ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `float` package and its `\newfloat` command it is possible to add new floating environments such as `graphique`, which defines a new counter of the same name then.

I've chosen the `grp` extension for the relevant `List of...` file and the counter should be reset within chapter, for example.

The `\listofgraphiques` is a wrapper command for `\listof{graphique}{Some title}`.

Additionally, some `\crefname` statements are used, just in case they are needed.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\newfloat{graphique}{tpbh}{grp}[chapter]


\newcommand{\listofgraphiquesname}{Table des graphiques}

\newcommand{\listofgraphiques}{%
  \listof{graphique}{\listofgraphiquesname}%
}

\crefname{graphique}{graphique}{graphiques}
\Crefname{graphique}{Graphique}{Graphiques}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listofgraphiques

\clearpage

See \cref{grp-lagraphique} or \Cref{grp-lagraphique} or \Cref{grp-lagraphique,grp-lagraphique-encore} for more information. 

\chapter{Alors\dots}

\begin{figure}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
\caption{Foo figure} \label{fig-lafigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{graphique}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
  \caption{C'est bon!}  \label{grp-lagraphique}
\end{graphique}

\chapter{Encore}

\begin{figure}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
\caption{La figure encore} \label{fig-lafigure-encore}
\end{figure}

\begin{graphique}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
  \caption{C'est bon encore!}  \label{grp-lagraphique-encore}
\end{graphique}




\end{document}
```

[image]

With `Graphique` in caps:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}




\newfloat{graphique}{tpbh}{grp}[chapter]


\newcommand{\listofgraphiquesname}{Table des graphiques}

\newcommand{\listofgraphiques}{%
  \listof{graphique}{\listofgraphiquesname}%
}

\crefname{graphique}{graphique}{graphiques}
\Crefname{graphique}{Graphique}{Graphiques}


\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{graph}{#1~#2}
\captionsetup[graphique]{name={Graphique},labelformat=graph}


\begin{document}



\listoffigures
\listofgraphiques

\clearpage

See \cref{grp-lagraphique} or \Cref{grp-lagraphique} or \Cref{grp-lagraphique,grp-lagraphique-encore} for more information. 

\chapter{Alors\dots}




\begin{figure}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
\caption{Foo figure} \label{fig-lafigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{graphique}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
  \caption{C'est bon!}  \label{grp-lagraphique}
\end{graphique}

\chapter{Encore}

\begin{figure}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
\caption{La figure encore} \label{fig-lafigure-encore}
\end{figure}

\begin{graphique}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
  \caption{C'est bon encore!}  \label{grp-lagraphique-encore}
\end{graphique}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As you can guess from my post: My knowledge of French language is legendary ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it ! I just have a minor issue, in the caption, the word graphique starts with small caps, while I want it to be like Graphique, how can do that ? Thanks!

Comment: @user105139: See the update please

Comment: @user105139: There is a 'gray' hook' at the left side of my answer, at the top, click on it and it should turn into a green hook. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

Instead of package `float` (see [Christian's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364591/9057)) you can use package [`newfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newfloat). It's part of the [`caption` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) and has a very easy understandable command `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` to declare new floats.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\listofgraphiquesname}{List of Graphics}
\addto\captionsfrench{% Switch name by language
  \def\listofgraphiquesname{Table des graphiques}%
}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[%
  fileext=grp,
  listname=\listofgraphiquesname,
  name=Graphique,
  placement=tpbh,
  within=chapter,
  chapterlistsgaps=on
]{graphique}

\crefname{graphique}{graphique}{graphiques}
\Crefname{graphique}{Graphique}{Graphiques}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listofgraphiques

\clearpage

See \cref{grp-lagraphique} or \Cref{grp-lagraphique} or \Cref{grp-lagraphique,grp-lagraphique-encore} for more information. 

\chapter{Alors\dots}




\begin{figure}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
\caption{Foo figure} \label{fig-lafigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{graphique}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
  \caption{C'est bon!}  \label{grp-lagraphique}
\end{graphique}

\chapter{Encore}

\begin{figure}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
\caption{La figure encore} \label{fig-lafigure-encore}
\end{figure}

\begin{graphique}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
  \caption{C'est bon encore!}  \label{grp-lagraphique-encore}
\end{graphique}


\end{document}
```

If you have a single language document, you even don't need to define `\listofgraphiquesname` but can simply use `listname={List of Graphics}`. I've added it to show how language dependent definitions could be done.

---

[The KOMA-Script bundle](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) provides a package [`tocbasic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbasic) that provides `\DeclareNewTOC`. The command is similar to `newfloat`'s `\DeclareFloatEnvironment` but provides additional features to configure the list entries. And the package loads KOMA-Script package `scrbase`, that provides an alternative interface to make language depending names:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% Define language depending names using scrbase
\newcommand*{\listofgraphiquesname}{List of Graphics}
\newcaptionname{french}{\listofgraphiquesname}{Table des graphiques}
\newcommand*{\graphiquename}{Graphic}
\newcaptionname{french}{\graphiquename}{Graphique}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=graphique,
  name=\graphiquename,
  float,
  floatpos=tpbh,
  counterwithin=chapter,
  listname=\listofgraphiquesname,
  tocentrynumwidth=2.3em,% hanging indent of the entries to the list of …
  tocentryindent=1.5em,% indent of entries to the list of …
]{gpo}

\crefname{graphique}{graphique}{graphiques}
\Crefname{graphique}{Graphique}{Graphiques}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listofgraphiques

\clearpage

See \cref{grp-lagraphique} or \Cref{grp-lagraphique} or \Cref{grp-lagraphique,grp-lagraphique-encore} for more information. 

\chapter{Alors\dots}

\begin{figure}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
\caption{Foo figure} \label{fig-lafigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{graphique}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
  \caption{C'est bon!}  \label{grp-lagraphique}
\end{graphique}

\chapter{Encore}

\begin{figure}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
\caption{La figure encore} \label{fig-lafigure-encore}
\end{figure}

\begin{graphique}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
  \caption{C'est bon encore!}  \label{grp-lagraphique-encore}
\end{graphique}


\end{document}
```

As you can see, these package does not need to use a KOMA-Script class but also work with several other classes like the standard `book` class.