# Create new environment for graphics with list of graphics

Tags: graphics, environments, labels

I need to create a new environment for a set of graphics figures, with counter on the caption so I can generate the list of all graphics like that :

```
\begin{graphic}
 \begin{center}
 \caption{Title of the graphic}
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{the graph.eps}
 \end{center}
\end{graphic}
```

so I can get in the title:

> Graphic I.1 Title of the graphic

> Graphic I.2 Title of the next graphic

and so on.
Thanks

Comment: why not `\listoffigures`  ?(you can change the title from Figure to Graphic)

Comment: but I need both, I don't want to change the figure environment, I need to create a same one with  different label

Comment: ok float or newfloat packges allow you to declare new float types

Comment: Here is an example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364709/