# How to add a label to the new float in TOC

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, floats, tocloft

This is a clearer question of [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621489/how-can-i-create-a-new-environment-looks-like-subfigure-and-add-its-label-to-its), I created a new float for table of images, I need a hack how to add it label to the list of \listofgraphiques.

```
\documentclass[openany]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newfloat{graphique}{tpbh}{grp}[chapter]
\newcommand{\listofgraphiquesname}{Table des graphiques}

\newcommand{\listofgraphiques}{%
  \listof{graphique}{\listofgraphiquesname}%
}
\newcommand{\cftgrppresnum}{\graphiquename~}%----> not working

\begin{document}
\listofgraphiques
\clearpage
\part{part one}
\chapter{Alors\dots}
\begin{graphique}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
  \caption{C'est bon!}  \label{grp-lagraphique}
\end{graphique}
\chapter{Encore}
\begin{graphique}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
  \caption{C'est bon encore!}  \label{grp-lagraphique-encore}
\end{graphique}
\part{part two}
\chapter{Alors\dots}
\begin{graphique}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
    \caption{C'est bon!}  \label{grp-lagraphique}
\end{graphique}
\chapter{Encore}
\begin{graphique}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{ente}
    \caption{C'est bon encore!}  \label{grp-lagraphique-encore}
\end{graphique}
\end{document}
```

[image: i want it to look like label 1.1 (label and number)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\listof` from [`float`](//ctan.org/pkg/float) completely overwrites `\l@graphique` as you would have defined it using [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft). You need to use `\listofgraphique` as defined naturally by `tocloft` when you issue `\newlistof`.

In order to make `tocloft` work with a float created by `float`, have to intervene by "nullifying" the associated float counter (`\c@graphique`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% Create a new float
\newfloat{graphique}{tpbh}{grp}[chapter]
\newcommand{\listofgraphiquesname}{Table des graphiques}
\makeatletter
% "Nullify" counter graphique defined by float
\let\c@graphique\relax
\makeatother
\newlistof[chapter]{graphique}{grp}{\listofgraphiquesname}% Create "List of..."

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fname@graphique}{Graphique}% Float name as defined by float
\renewcommand{\cftgraphiquepresnum}{\fname@graphique~}% Prefix to number in "List of..."
\setlength{\cftgraphiquenumwidth}{7em}% To accommodate for the wide "number" that now has a prefix
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofgraphique

\chapter{A chapter}

\begin{graphique}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
  \caption{A caption}
\end{graphique}

\end{document}
```