# How create a Table Of Appendices?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I need to create a Table Of Appendices and I don't know how doing this. I don't find solution on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ or on LaTeX documentation.

The table of appendices must look like a classical table of contents with chapters names but without pages numbers.

Someone can help me to do this ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

%%%%%% USE PACKAGE %%%%%%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

%%%%%% A LOT OF CHAPTERS WHICH ARE ON THE tableofcontents %%%%%% 

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APPENDICES}

\vspace*{8cm}
\begin{center}
    \Huge\textbf{APPENDICES}
\end{center}

%%%%%% TABLE OF APPENDICES HERE %%%%%%

\appendix

\chapter*{A - Document SOLR}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.70]{./images/document_solr.png}
    \end{figure}

\chapter*{B - Administration des rapports}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.40]{./images/page_gestion_rapport.png}
    \end{figure}

\chapter*{C - Extrait rapport mensuel}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \rotatebox{90}{
            \includegraphics[scale=0.40]{./images/extrait_rapport.png}
        }
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT 1 :**

I added :

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{tocloft,titlesec}
\newcommand{\listappendixname}{Tables des annexes}
\newlistof{appendix}{apc}{\listappendixname}

\AtBeginEnvironment{appendices}{%
  \clearpage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Annexes}
  \write\@auxout{%
    \string\let\string\latex@tf@toc\string\tf@toc% Store the original `\tf@toc` file handle
    \string\let\string\tf@toc\string\tf@apc% 
  }% Naughty trick
  \titleformat 
  {\chapter} 
  [display]
  {\huge\bfseries\filcenter} 
  {\Large \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp} \thechapter} 
  {1.5ex}{}
  {}
}

\AtEndEnvironment{appendices}{%
  \write\@auxout{%
    \string\let\string\tf@toc\string\latex@tf@toc% 
  }% Naughty trick, restoring the old `\tf@toc` number, to be able to write stuff to the real `.toc` again.
}
```

And :

```
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Annexes}

\vspace*{8cm}
\begin{center}
    \Huge\textbf{Annexes}
\end{center}

%%%%%% NEW LINES %%%%%%

\listofappendix

\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Proof of Theorem One}
    \chapter{Proof of Theorem Two}
\end{appendices}
```

I obtain this error : `! Improper \spacefactor.\@->\spacefactor\@m {} \begin{appendices}`

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I only know the related question [Redefining \listoffigures and \listoftables as tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285450/124842).

Comment: See my answer  at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345992/31729 as a possible solution

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thank's, result seem's to be good with my expectation. However, i got mistakes ... I edited my question with new lines.

Comment: @NicolasLamblin: You forgot the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` wrapper around the code -- see the linked answer again in order to place the two macros at the correct position!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer of course sorry ! Thank's a lot !!! Result is perfect even if I don't understood lines signification.

Comment: @NicolasLamblin: You can remove the `titlesec` related stuff most likely, that was only necessary in the other question